# How to print a key from an array and then to print the key from another array?

Tags: arrays

array 1 is

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 00001 [2] => 01000 [3] => 00100 [4] => 00010 [5] => 10000 )
```

array 2 is

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => 11000 [2] => 00011 [3] => 00110 [4] => 00011 [5] => 10001 [6] => 10100 [7] => 10010 [8] => 01010 [9] => 01001 [10] => 00101 )
```

$endArray = 00001, 11000, 01000, 00011 etc etc....

a value from array 1, the next value from array 2, the next value from array 1, the next value from array 2.

Comment: What happens after the 10th print?

Comment: The language is PHP. Actually it is 4 arrays. array1 has 5 values, array2 has 10 values, array 3 has also 10 values and array 4 has 5 values. The endresult should be: (from array1),fromarray2.....,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3,fromarray4

Answer (score 1):

Here is some pseudo code because I don't know what language you want to implement this. I made the assumption you only want to print both arrays (and not the remaining).

```
int lengthA = size(array1);
int lengthB = size(array2);
int smallestSize = 0;

if(lengthA > lengthB) smallestSize = lengthA;
else if(lengthB > lengthA) smallestSize = lengthB;
else smallestSize = lengthA;

for(int i = 0; i < smallestSize; i++){
    print(array1[i] + ", " + array2[i]);
}
```